# syntax error near unexpected token `'../lib/cli.js''

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, syntax, nvm

The file in question:

```
#!/root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.5.0/bin/node
require('../lib/cli.js')(process)
```

- Node -v 17.5.0

  NPM -v 8.4.1

  PM2 -v 5.1.2

  Next.js v11.1.3

Trying to run in an Amazon EC2 instance on the default Linux AMI. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what fixed it. But the ancient artform of nuke everything and start from scratch fixed it.

EDIT: Specifically, I had some legacy flag `--interpreter bash` that I appended to the `pm2 run` script (probably referencing some 2016 stack overflow answer). Removing this fixed all issues I had with PM2

Comment: what did you do exactly ?

Comment: @LouisLecouturier Just added an improvement to the answer.